# How do I stop my screen from flickering when I wave my hand across my camera?

Tags: screen, camera, front-camera

Whenever I wave my hand or finger over my front camera, it causes my screen to flicker off and then back on in 2-3 seconds. It does not matter what app I am using; it always occurs. What could be causing this?

Comment: It could be a hardware malfunction, how old is the phone?

Comment: Brand new, only a few months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was caused by installing [SuperN64](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supern64.n64.emulator). Strange that it caused something across the entire phone and every app, not just itself.